# Unix batch file run using selenium C# automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a requirement,like having list of .bat batch files i need automate the batch  using selenium C#? is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Selenium. 
Use the following code. Create a function which takes in FileName and WorkingDirectory as parameters:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\BatchFiles\\Demo.bat";
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\BatchFiles";
proc.Start();
```